# Will rascal supports MAC M1 - Monterey OS?

Tags: eclipse, rascal

I have java 8.
I have installed the eclipse latest version as this supports ARM64 chip  - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-12/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers
And when i try to add rascal - https://update.rascal-mpl.org/stable/

Eclipse throws an error -

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: The Rascal MetaProgramming Language 0.18.3 (rascal-feature.feature.group 0.18.3)
  Missing requirement: rascal_eclipse 0.18.3 (rascal_eclipse 0.18.3) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.core.runtime [0.0.0,3.19.0)' but it could not be found
  
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: The Rascal MetaProgramming Language 0.18.3 (rascal-feature.feature.group 0.18.3)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; rascal_eclipse [0.18.3,0.18.3]
```

Can someone guide me to resolve this error?
Is this due to the installation of latest version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

The key part of the error is

> requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.core.runtime [0.0.0,3.19.0)'

This is saying the org.eclipse.core.runtime plug-in is required with a version less than 3.19.0.

The last version of Eclipse with that plug-in at a suitable version was Eclipse 4.16 (2020-06). So it isn't go to install on the ARM64 release. The Rascal plug-ins would have to be updated to run on anything newer.

Eclipse 2020-06 was the last Eclipse that only required Java 8 to run, possibly that is something to do with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. 
So if i understand correctly this cannot be run on M1?

Comment: Note with the arm64 Eclipse. My understanding is you can run x86_64 code on an m1 so you might be able to use the old x86_64 Eclipse 2020-06 (with an x86_64 Java). But currently I only have x86_64 Macs so I can't help with that.

Comment: I tried doing that - installing older version of eclipse with x86_64 https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-06/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers. But that didn't work, couldn't even launch eclipse. 
Thanks your feedback and suggestions.

Comment: excellent answer. I have a pre-release here of Rascal that can help. It is written for JDK 11 and so it does not have the issues you identified. https://releases.usethesource.io/maven/org/rascalmpl/rascal-update-site/0.22.0/rascal-update-site-0.22.0.zip

Comment: the zip should be added as an update site from "Archive..." and this will give you a snapshot release of rascal-0.22.0